How to set a custom starting point in a text RPG game in Java?
The thing is, I'm working on a text-based role-playing game in Java. My game always runs sequentially, so if I'm updating the latest story thread, I have to start from the beginning and run the entire game until I reach the point I want to check.
My question is: is it possible to create a "savePoint" or some debugging option to immediately get to the point I need?
I didn't even try anything because I don't know how to implement it.. :(
Little fragment of my GameLoop:
public class GameLoop { // todo -> modularizar esta clase en un futuro para manejabilidad y comprensión
public static void run(GameContext gc, PlayerInteractions pi) {
    Npc npc = new Npc();
    gc.getConsolePresentation().displayStats(gc.getGuiInteraction(),gc.getPlayer(),null);

    String playerName = "";
    do {
        gc.getPlayer().setName(gc.getGuiInteraction());
        playerName = gc.getGuiInteraction().getInput();
    } while (playerName == null || playerName.trim().isEmpty());
    gc.getGuiInteraction().continueGame();
    gc.getPlayer().setName(playerName);
    gc.getGuiInteraction().showMessage(gc.getPlayer().getName());

        //inicio del juego
    GameStoryTeller.narrar(0, null);
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput();
    GameStoryTeller.narrar(1, gc.getPlayer());
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput();
    GameStoryTeller.narrar(47,null);
    GameVoiceOver.dialogo(19,null);
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput(); GameVoiceOver.separador(gc.getGuiInteraction());

        //estadísticas iniciales del jugador
    GameStoryTeller.narrar(2, null);
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput();
    GameStoryTeller.narrar(3, gc.getPlayer());
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput();

        //interacción inicial con NPC
    Npc.interactuarNPC00(gc.getGuiInteraction());
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput();
    String respuesta = pi.opcionEscogida0(gc.getGuiInteraction(), gc.getPlayer());
    npc.interactuarNPC01(respuesta);
    gc.getGuiInteraction().pauseForUserInput();
    Npc.interactuarNPC02(gc.getPlayer());


Without any example code, it's hard to give this an answer beyond "yes, it's possible" - we know nothing about your game or how it's implemented, beyond the fact it's Java.

It is based on a sequential thread of execution, which is managed from the same run() method of my GameLoop class and asks the user to interact by entering options. The thing would be to put an intersection point in that run(), so you can start from where you need it. I do not know if I explained well... :(

You will need to do some code restructuring to allow restart.  For a start, you "game loop" actually needs to be a loop.  And you need to loop over the "scenes" (or whatever they are) in your game.  You could make each scene a method, and put the methods into an array and have your loop iterate over the array, calling the methods in turn.  Try that idea for a start.

You can create method for saving to file and reload from file.
If it's just for you, you can use saving to text file:
public static void Save(){
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("name_of_file.txt"))) {
        writer.write("code you want to save;");
        writer.write("next code");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("code on new line;");
        //your code for saving to text file
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("error message");
    }
}

code for reading:
public static void Load() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name_of_file.txt"))) {
        String text = reader.readLine();
        while (text != null) {
            String[] data = text.split(";");
            String firsPart = data[0];
            //your code to implement loading progress
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("error message");
    }
}

Or you can use ObjectsOutputStream/ObjectIntputStream if you have progress stored as an object
